# I can't get KeyEvent listener to work

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

Ok, first off.
If I do System.out.println(e);
that does print when I push the key. However I can not for the life of me figure out how to store this into an int. My IDE gives me no errors if I do
int pressed = e.KEY_PRESSED(); or int pressed = e.getKeyCode(); 
but if I try to print pressed nothing happens.

I've been trying to get this to work for hours and Googling KeyEvent handlers and the Javadocs seem to be of little help to me on this.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    pressed = e.getKeyCode();
    System.out.println(pressed);
```

## }

```
    do{
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        do{
            if(pressed == 37||pressed==38||pressed==39||pressed==40){
                lastvalid=pressed;
            }
        }
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < time + speed);

        switch(lastvalid){
            case 37: catarloc.set(0, (Integer)catarloc.get(0)-1); break;
            case 38: catarloc.set(1, (Integer)catarloc.get(1)-1); break;
            case 39: catarloc.set(0, (Integer)catarloc.get(0)+1); break;
            case 40: catarloc.set(1, (Integer)catarloc.get(1)+1); break;
        }

        if(Math.random() > .95 || apples < 1){
            applearray[(int)(Math.random()*100/2.8)][(int)(Math.random()*100/4)] = true;
            apples++;
        }
        score+=catarloc.size()-1;
        label.setText("Score     "+ score);
        mainWindow.repaint();
    }
    while(win == false || lose == false);
```

Comment: What library you use (Swing/SWT/etc)?

Comment: Can you include the source for your listener and usage of the key event?

Comment: Done, including the parts that use the input

Comment: What component are you installing the KeyListener to? Could it possible be a focus issue? So if you click on the control that has the KeyListener and then press a key, does it receive the event?

Answer (score 1):

What about [`keyEvent.getKeyCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode%28%29)? It returns an int. `KEY_PRESSED` is a static final int member on KeyEvent and represents an event when a key is pressed down, not the actual key code.

Update: (Whoops) I see that you already tried getKeyCode. What happens if you print [`getKeyLocation`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyLocation%28%29) or [`getKeyChar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29)?

Comment: Evidently it is an odd thing. I have been trying to get the arrow keys to work and if I try those first no key input is detected. I have to try a regular key before the ones I was trying.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of event:

- `keyEvent.getKeyChar()` gives you the character associated with the key, but only for `KEY_TYPED` events. Otherwise it returns `CHAR_UNDEFINED`
- `keyEvent.getKeyCode()` gives you the virtual key code, but only for `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events. Otherwise it returns `VK_UNDEFINED`.